# What drawbacks are there if we fire events after projection?

Tags: event-sourcing, cucumber-java, axon, eventual-consistency

*Some project context - FYI*

In our system we use some acceptance testing with cucumber. In the test runs we use a fully setup system of microservices (local machine). The event sourcing is managed by an Axon Event Store.

*Scenario*

We apply commands to aggregates and fire business events. Projection is implemented as an event handler.
Other services are listening the the business event and read the written data (REST).

We do it that way to keep our events small.

To overcome the eventual consistency period between business event and projection, while reading occurs in other service, we have many statements in our cucumber steps like

```
Thread.sleep(5000L);
```

But the sleep value depends on the performance index of underlying hardware. So tests are brittle.

*Question*
Would it be an option to fire events after the projection has written data? So we could read the data with guarantee of actuality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firing events (through your domain layer) just for the sake of synchronizing your read model sounds a bit of to me. I would suggest that you can subscribe to your read model and get notified when it is synchronized. We have implemented something similar with [STOMP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/stomp.html).

In our case our frontend subscribes to a users cart and receives updates for it.

**EDIT:**

Off course you can also use `axon-server`s query bus. If you can't afford a full blown cluster you can still store your events elsewhere (jpa, jdbc, mongodb) and configure your querybus to use the free Standard edition of `axon-server`.